# Size of a LinkedList in C#

Tags: c#, linked-list, size

I am porting a Java program to C#.

In Java to get the size of a `LinkedList<T>` I do:

`int size = list.size();`

However, I cannot find a similar method in C#. I know that the point of a linked list is not to know the size of it, but since I am using it for a buffer it would be a good idea to have a counter internally in the list to return its size.

Comment: Do you mean `Size` in *byte* or the number of items, which can be added before more memory is allocated?

Comment: Have you tried Count()?

Comment: Number of items. Thanks count worked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to use the [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t56y0h99.aspx) property.

Additionally, `LinkedList` implements `IEnumerable`, so all methods for that interface are also avaliable, including `Count()`.

Comment: Just to add to this answer: If you're having trouble calling this method, just remember to to include the following using statement at the beginning of your file: `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Which one is faster? The property or the method?

Comment: @IronMan84 Thanks for the update. I just updated my answer, your addition is valid if OP will use the `IEnumerable` methods.

Comment: @Dimme: You can answer that question yourself. Obtain a stopwatch, write the code both ways, and then you'll know.

Comment: I tried but my stopwatch resolution is only tenths of a second.

Comment: @Dimme if the class implements ICollection, a call to IEnumerable.Count() will use ICollection.Count property as return value. As LinkedList implements both, trying to profile both the property and the method should give you the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the Count Property? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t56y0h99.aspx

Answer (score 2):

In C# equivalents to Java's *size* are *Length* in arrays and *Count* in objects that implement *ICollection* interface. Arrays also contains *Count* but it is implemented explicitly and requires casting to *ICollection*. There is also *IEnumerable* interface that is implemented by all objects that allow iteration through their elements. The *IEnumerable* contains extension method called *Count()*. Note, that it is a method, not property. Some real collections also expose *Capacity* property, which indicates how many memory there is allocated for elements. *Capacity* is always greathers than or equals *Count*. If your list is large, you can use *LongCount()* method from *IEnumerable*. Note, that *Count()* method from *IEnumerable* also allows to count elements that satisfies given criteria. That may be usefull.

Samples:

```
LinkedList<string> linkedList = new LinkedList<string>();

int32 size3 = linkedList.Count; // From ICollection
int32 size2 = linkedList.Count(); // From IEnumerable
int64 bigSize = linkedList.LongCount(); // From IEnumerable

int32 size4 = linkedList.Count(s => s == "a"); // Count only strings equals "a"
```

For further reading see: [System.Collections Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145035.aspx) that contains all information about common .NET collections.